# unstable behaviour of requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I am experiencing some issue with `requireJS`, to which I am not familiar

I have this tree 
app/

```
public/
 master.html
 js/
   main.js
   app.js
   lib/ 
      jquery.js
      require.js
   vendor
       upload/
             vendor/
               dependency_upload.js //a bunch of dependencies file
             ulpload.js
       slider/
             dependency_slider.js //a bunch of dependencies file
             slider.js
```

in `master.html` file :

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

In my `main.js` file

```
require(['js/lib/jquery.js']);

require({
    paths: {
        'dependency_upload': 'vendor/upload/vendor/dependencies'
    }
}, ['js/vendor/upload/upload.js'], function(App) {
    App.upload();
});


require(['js/app.js']);

require({
    paths: {
        'dependency_slider' : 'vendor/slider/dependencies'
    }
}, ['js/vendor/slider/slider.js'], function(App) {
    App.slider();
});
```

and each of `upload.js` or `slider.js` have the following structure. Here `$myfunction` stands here respectively for upload and slider

```
define(['dependency_$myfunction'],function() {
        function $myfunction(){ 
            ...
        }
        return{
            $myfunction: $myfunction
        }
    }
);
```

I have two problems,

1) The behaviour of the `js` loading is unstable : once two, `jquery is not recognized`. Btw, `upload.js` and `slider.js` share dependencies and some function of `slider.js` that are set inside these shared dependencies are said to be undefined (perhaps some files are loaded twice ?). So, am I correct with my `requireJS` usage ?

Comment: "paths: { 'dependencies' }" is not valid JavaScript (nor is "function upload/slider(){ ... }" )

Comment: @kryger I know that, it just to make my post clearer ;)

Comment: Well it is not. Put real valid code.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias I cleared it up !

Answer (score 1):

The module loading is asynchronous, so if you really need jQuery loaded before the other module you have to do one of two things:

1 - Use the callback function from your require of jquery so that you don't try to load the other until jquery is loaded:

```
require(['js/lib/jquery.js'], function($) {    
    require({
        paths: {
            'dependency_upload': 'vendor/upload/vendor/dependencies'
        }
    }, ['js/vendor/upload/upload.js'], function(App) {
        App.upload();
    });
});
```

2 - (and this is the preferred way) use a [shim configuration](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to tell RequireJS that any time you request upload.js it needs to load jquery first.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Btw, in fact, `upload.js` `slider.js` have to be loaded for the same page and they share libraries. How can I deal with  that knowing I want to keep them separate, is there a best practice ?

Comment: RequireJS caches module requests, so if both upload and slider `require(['foo'])` it will only be loaded once and returned to both